# How to create dynamically nested objects and object properties in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'd like to create properties and nested objects with properties in typescript, but I'm getting an error.

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'bank_account_ownership_verification')

Here is my code

```js
const account: any = {};

account.documents.bank_account_ownership_verification.files = this.file.value;
```

Comment: `account.documents` is `undefined`. You can't access property `bank_account_ownership_verification'` of `undefined`

Comment: I understand, but I tought this piece of code would dynamically create those objects and allow me to add property data or other objects?

Comment: No, it doesn't do this for you. You have to do it, either step by step, with a nested object or with a library like Lodash.

Comment: What about square brackets like this: account['documents']['other'] ??? I though this would do it but received an error with this too

Comment: Square brackets have a similar behavior in this case. This question has nothing to do with TypeScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without additional libraries you can either assign properties in multiple steps

```
const account: any = {};

account.documents = {};
account.documents.bank_account_ownership_verification = {};
account.documents.bank_account_ownership_verification.files =  ​this.file.value;
```

or nested properties

```
const account: any = {};

account.documents = { bank_account_ownership_verification: { files: this.file.value } };
```